# How do I position dual screen with precision on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, window

So I have two monitor that are at different height (I bought the wrong stand, but I like it this way

[image: My dual monitor setup]

I want to position them so that when I move a window from screen to screen it is at the exact same level.

But windows parameter doesn't allow us to use cm, mm or pixel number to position the two screens.

[image: windows parameter]

Is there a hidden setting in order to do that ?

Comment: related: [Change Relative Size of Multiple Monitors](https://superuser.com/q/1210729/241386)

Comment: Related: [Registry Keys to determine monitor positions](https://superuser.com/questions/106749/what-registry-key-or-windows-file-determines-where-monitors-are-placed-in-a-mult)

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old post, but I am posting here anyway in the hopes that I can still help someone who has the same question.

After searching extensively for a way to do this, I came across some relevant C++ code that appeared to do the trick, so I wrote a small command line utility to achieve pixel-perfect adjustments to multiple monitors. It also only needs to be run once and is persistent through reboots.

The command works like this:

```
dpedit.exe <monitorIndex> <X> <Y> [<monitorIndex2> <X> <Y> ...]
```

For instance, I figured out that in *my* monitor setup, my secondary monitor was near-exactly 21 pixels lower down than my primary monitor. So, I simply ran the command `dpedit.exe 2 -1920 21` to position my **2nd** monitor **1,920 pixels left** of and **21 pixels down** from the first, leading to the result pictured below.

[Monitor positioning result because I can't embed images yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9iXg.jpg)

Feel free to check out the tool here: [DPEdit](https://github.com/programmer2514/DPEdit)

Comment: Explaining HOW to use this utility to solve the problem will make this an answer. Right now it is a comment with a suggestion, and it is NOT and answer.

Comment: @music2myear I updated the answer. Should I add more of a description, or is this sufficient? (Sorry for the noob mistake, I'm still fairly new to this site)

Comment: If this tool uses the registry, presumably the monitor positions can be adjusted by entering the settings into the registry?

Comment: @SteveSmith This tool does modify the registry, but indirectly, using the `ChangeDisplaySettingsExW()` method from windows.h. In essence, I know _what_ it does but I am unsure exactly _where_ in the registry it modifies.

Comment: It works well, just not obvious which way to move it to align it.  I have upvoted it.

Answer (score 1):

no, I don't think there would be a way for that.

Searching for it I could find just one old post which confirms this (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings-winpc/windows-10-multiple-monitor-alignment-unwanted/208f3b88-18f2-4a8a-8534-d113cb017047)

Answer (score 0):

There's a GitHub project that provides a GUI interface for positioning your monitors in virtual space. It functions the same as the default Windows tool, but with increased (pixel-level) accuracy.

I used it to align my monitors in a very odd configuration and was very satisfied with its performance.

[Screenshot of Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDM4r.png)

[Link to GitHub repository](https://github.com/programmer2514/DPEdit-GUI)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1208361)